# Insert Into Table with String Insert Or Table Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a table called @Tbl1, Each GROUP is 1 row and I have to extract the number of rows for each to @Tbl_Insert type.

```
 Declare @Tbl1 Table (TableName NVARCHAR(250),ColumnName NVARCHAR(250),DataType NVARCHAR(250),DataValue NVARCHAR(250),InGroup NVARCHAR(250))
 Declare @Tbl_Insert Table (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(250), Age INT)

 -- Sample Data
 Insert Into @Tbl1 values ('@Tbl_Insert','ID','INT','1','Group1'),('@Tbl_Insert','Name','NVARCHAR(250)','John.Adam','Group1'),('@Tbl_Insert','Age','INT','10','Group1')
 Insert Into @Tbl1 values ('@Tbl_Insert','ID','INT','2','Group2'),('@Tbl_Insert','Name','NVARCHAR(250)','Andy.Law','Group2'),('@Tbl_Insert','Age','INT','18','Group2')
```

I can convert @tbl1 to row by row into @Table_TEMP

```
Declare @Table_TEMP (Data nvarchar(max))

 Insert Into @Table_TEMP
 SELECT LEFT([DataValues] , LEN([DataValues] )-1) 
    FROM  @Tbl1 AS extern
    CROSS APPLY
    (

        SELECT Concat('''', Replace( ISNULL([DataValue],''), '''','' ) + ''',')
        FROM  @Tbl1 AS intern
        WHERE extern.InGroup = intern.InGroup
        Order By InGroup, ColumnName
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) pre_trimmed ( [DataValues])
    GROUP BY InGroup,  [DataValues]
```

I have to extract the number of rows in @Tbl1 ( Or @Table_TEMP)  to @Tbl_Insert.

I don't want to use cursor to loop Insert row by row in @Table_TEMP, because, when you met with big data (example > 10000 rows). It's run to slow.

Please help.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've just edit the question for clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do both @Tbl_Insert & create 1 store to do like PARSENAME. It's improved performance.

```
create  function dbo.fnGetCsvPart(@csv varchar(8000),@index tinyint, @last bit = 0)
returns varchar(4000)
as
/* function to retrieve 0 based "column" from csv string */
begin
    declare @i int; set @i = 0
    while 1 = 1
    begin
        if @index = 0
        begin
            if @last = 1 or charindex(',',@csv,@i+1) = 0
                return substring(@csv,@i+1,len(@csv)-@i+1)
            else
                return substring(@csv,@i+1,charindex(',',@csv,@i+1)-@i-1)
        end
        select @index = @index-1, @i = charindex(',',@csv,@i+1)
        if @i = 0 break
    end
    return null
end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I found sample in stackorverflow

```
Declare @tbl_Temp Table (Data NVARCHAR(MAX))
 Declare @tbl2 Table (A NVARCHAR(MAX),B NVARCHAR(MAX),C NVARCHAR(MAX))
 Insert Into @tbl_Temp values ('a1*b1*c1')
 INSERT INTO @tbl2 (A,B,C)
 SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data,'*','.'),3)
      ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data,'*','.'),2)
     ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Data,'*','.'),1)
 FROM @tbl_Temp

select * from @tbl2
```

It's nearly the same, but,

1. My data have "DOT", can not use PARSENAME
2. I must know numbers of DOT to Build Dynamics SQL??
3. PARSENAME only support 3 "DOT", It's null when More Dot.
   EXAMPLE:

Declare @ObjectName nVarChar(1000)
Set @ObjectName = 'HeadOfficeSQL1.Northwind.dbo.Authors'

SELECT
        PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 5) as Server4,
        PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 4) as Server,
        PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 3) as DB,
        PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 2) as Owner,
        PARSENAME(@ObjectName, 1) as Object

Answer (score 0):

If, i understand correctly you will need to use `apply` in order to fetch the records & insert the data into other table

```
insert into @Tbl_Insert (ID, Name, Age)
select max(a.id) [id], max(a.Name) [Name], max(a.Age) [Age] from @Tbl1 t
cross apply
          (values
             (case when t.ColumnName = 'ID' then t.DataValue end,
              case when t.ColumnName = 'Name' then t.DataValue end,
              case when t.ColumnName = 'Age' then t.DataValue end, t.InGroup)
          ) as a(id, Name, Age, [Group])
group by a.[Group]

select * from @Tbl_Insert
```